# How can I listen for updates to comments and their replies with firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, svelte

I have a simple messaging/commenting system where there are top level comments, and replies to that top level comment.

I have `posts/{id}/comments` which has the top level comments. A `posts/{id}/comments/{id}/replies` has all the replies for that particular comment.

I am using svelte, and here is how I've got my data being loaded so far to just get the top level:

```
async function loadComments(after?: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> | undefined) {
  unsubscribe?.();

  const fsdb = getFirestore();

  const q = after
    ? query(
        collection(fsdb, 'posts', post.id, 'comments'),
        orderBy('sentAt', 'desc'),
        limit(5),
        startAfter(after)
      )
    : query(collection(fsdb, 'posts', post.id, 'comments'), orderBy('sentAt', 'desc'), limit(5));

  unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    let res: PostCommentWithReplies[] = [];

    lastVisibleComment = querySnapshot.docs.at(querySnapshot.size - 1);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const comment = doc.data() as PostComment;
      comment.id = doc.id;

      if (comment.numReplies > 0) {
        // get those replies and real time updates
      }

      const obj: PostCommentWithReplies = {
        comment: comment
        replies: [] // the reply comments
      };

      res.push(obj);
    });
  });
}
```

What are my options here to do this properly? Thanks

Comment: Could you edit the question to more clearly state the problem you're having here?  "What are my options" is unclear.

Comment: You can also use rxfire to stream queried data. stream updated data.

Answer (score 0):

In Firestore, queries are shallow: "They only return documents in a particular collection or collection group **and do not return subcollection data**" (excerpt from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#querying)).

This is valid for "one time" queries (i.e. done through the `getDoc()`method) as well as for listening to the results of a query with the for `onSnapshot()` method.

So, with your current data model, you would have to set a listener for all comments **and** replies subcollections...

You could adapt your data model and put in the **same** subcollection the comments and replies to a post and use a specific field (`level or` type`?) to differentiate the level of the documents in the hierarchy (parent = comments and children = replies), as well as saving the comment ID in each reply doc in order to display, in your front end, all comments and their replies via a hierarchical visualization.